# Creating a new column on conditional of two other columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns. I want to create a new column and input whichever column has the longest string. so

```
        column_a        column_b             column_c

   0  'dog is fast'   'dog is faster'      'dog is faster' (desired output)
```

I tried this code but got an error saying that int is not iterable, I was thinking in merging the series after to the df. I wasn't sure how to implement it right away into a column of the df.

```
column_c = pd.Series()

 for i in len(df.column_a):
  if len(df.column_a.iloc[i]) >= len(df.column_b.iloc[0]):
    column_c.append(df.column_a.iloc[i])
  else:
    column_c.append(df.column_b.iloc[i])
```

any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

Given sample data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['fast', 'faster'], ['slower', 'slow']])
        0       1
0    fast  faster
1  slower    slow

df['column_c'] = df.apply(lambda x:max(x, key=len), 1)
```

Output:

```
        0       1 column_c
0    fast  faster   faster
1  slower    slow   slower
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.where` with `str.len`

```
df['column_c']=np.where(df.column_a.str.len()>df.column_b.str.len(),df.column_a,df.column_b)
df
Out[301]: 
        column_a         column_b         column_c
0  'dog is fast'  'dog is faster'  'dog is faster'
```

Answer (score 2):

*Can use df.apply()*

```
df['column_c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x[0]) > len(x[1]) else x[1], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.apply`. You need to apply on specific columns if you have more than two columns in your dataframe

```
df['column_c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x[0]) > len(x[1]) else x[1], axis = 1)

     column_a        column_b        column_c
0   'dog is fast'   'dog is faster' 'dog is faster'
```

Comment: oh thats great, I read the apply doc and didn't mention you could do multiple columns. thank you.

Comment: On axis 1, the function will be applied on all columns. In this case there are two columns, so accessing then using x[0] and x[1]